# How to mount volume without using docker

Tags: kubernetes, docker-run, containerd, runc, cri-o

In order to mount a directory to a container i used bind mounts https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/
Now i'm trying to find a way to replace `$docker run -v` command.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using kubernetes as that is there in your tag. You can mount a volume as hostpath.

In Pod spec:

```
  volumeMounts:
    - name: config
      mountPath: <PATH IN CONTAINER>
  volumes:
    - name: config
      hostPath:
        path: <YOUR LOCAL DIR PATH>
```

Check out https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/ for more details

Comment: Is there a way to mount volumes via the arguments of crictl command? Unfortunately is not our choice to configure pod spec